# King who sacrificed for pre-war Kurukshetra

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, pandavas, kurukshetra

Before the Mahabharata war, a Kshatriya with a flawless body had to be sacrificed. In the Pandavas camp, only Krishna and Arjuna had flawless bodies but they couldn't be sacrificed. So Aravan came forward and offered him on the condition that he wanted to marry before he dies.

Aravan or Iravan is the son of Arjuna and Ulupi, the Naga Princess who came forward for the ritual.

**Is that true that Aravan was sacrificed in the pre-war of Kurukshetra?**

Comment: Where did u get this information that such a sacrifice was required, I don't remember reading anything like this.

Comment: @VAggarwal, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iravan

Answer (score 3):

No, Aravan (or Iravan) was not sacrificed. Aravan, son of Arjuna, was killed by rakshasa Alambusha on the [8th day of the battle](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118438.html), and the latter was slain by Ghatotkacha.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iravan specifically the parts on Tamil cults

Comment: @iruvar - might be folklore. Plenty of other folklore like Abhimanyu understanding chakravyuha in womb, Gandhari seeing duryodhana to make him invincible, sahdeva and krishna eating Pandu's corpse etc. But these are not as per Mahabharata